# Vue.js with TypeScript - getting the type of the ref child component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

My parent component has a child component called with reference passed to it:

```
<child
  ref="childRef"
/>
```

Now from the parent component I want to run the function which is inside child component like this:

```
mounted() {
  (this.$refs.childRef as any).testFunction();
}
```

Of course it's working fine with any type, but how do I set the correct type to run this function?

If I use the type of the component itself:

```
(this.$refs.childRef as Child).testFunction();
```

it still says that property `testFunction` does not exist on type 'Vue'.

I use the 2 version of Vue.js.

My child component:

```
@Component({})
export default class Child extends Mixins(CustomMixin) {
  testFunction() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Also I found this solution to run the function:

```
(this.$refs.childRef as Child & { testFunction:() => void }).testFunction();
```

It updates the Child type with the method `testFunction()` and it actually works. Although I don't know if this is a good approach.

Comment: It should work.

Comment: It wasn't originally shown how Child is defined. This is very specific to your case, which is vue-class-component and not just every component. Since `Child` in your case is a class, I'd expect this to work. The "solution" is a hack that fixes some problem with types, it's not a correct solution. You need to add details how the problem is observed, because TS errors at build time and in IDE are totally different things. Consider providing a way to reproduce it, e.g. at Stackblitz with some vue+ts template

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and it should work as child component `ref` holds the instance of Child component only. Here is the code snippet. Please have a look and crosscheck with your code to find out the root cause.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child ref="childCom"></child>
</div>

Vue.component('child', {
    methods: {
    testFunction() {
        console.log('test function call')
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    (this.$refs.childCom as Child).testFunction();
  }
});
```

Demo Link : https://jsfiddle.net/w6bjso78/

Comment: Did you test it? `Child` is not a class, it cannot be used as a type for an instance. This is TS problem. The code without types is likely workable.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry, SO code snippet not support typescript. Hence, I just added a jsfiddle link. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah I also updated my question with Child component and one possible solution. The child component is exported as a Vue type. I use Mixins but it's also the same with extends Vue too.

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the solution I found:

```
(this.$refs.childRef as Child & { testFunction:() => void }).testFunction();
```

It works although I don't know if this is a clean apporach. It updates the Child type with a void method `testFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this:

```js
const MyComponent = ref<InstanceType<typeof MyFileBoard>>()
```

You can read more details [there](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/402).

Answer (score 0):

I always using setup and lang="ts"

I think that the best method is:

```
// child-component.vue

export interface IEtapa {
  fetchEnviosContar(): Promise<void>
}

const fetchEnviosContar = async ():Promise<void>=>{
  console.log("hello world")
})
defineExpose<IEtapa>({
  fetchEnviosContar,
})

// parent-component.vue

import Etapas, { IEtapa } from '../components/etapas/index.vue'

const refEtapasComponent = ref<IEtapa | null>(null)

refEtapasComponent.value?.fetchEnviosContar()
```